# Flutter error type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list:

```dart
List<dynamic> activityDays = [];
```

And this code:

```
getItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (widget.user.uid.isNotEmpty) {
  // ignore: missing_return
  snapshot.data.documents.map<Column>((f) {
  if (f.documentID == widget.currentList.keys.elementAt(widget.i)) {
    f.data.forEach((a, b) {
      if (a == "activities") {
        List<dynamic> markMap = f.data['activities'];
        for (var element in markMap) {
          activityDays.add(element['days']);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}).toList();
```

[image]

And printing the list gives the result:
**[[M, T, L], [T, T, L]]**

But when I am trying to get an item from the list it gives me error:
**type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

I am using it like this:

```dart
GroupedCheckbox(
  itemList: activityDays.elementAt(i),
  checkedItemList: checkedItemList,
  onChanged: (itemList) {
    setState(() {
      selectedItemList = itemList;
      print('SELECTED ITEM LIST $itemList');
    });
  },
  orientation: CheckboxOrientation.VERTICAL,
  checkColor: Colors.blue,
  activeColor: Colors.red,
),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Such error meaning is we are missing to use typecast like..as dynamic while to store.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried just declaring your lists as `List<String>` to avoid variable type conflict?

Comment: Yes but the problem is that it is a list that contains multiple lists like: List<list>. Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining data type as `List<dynamic>` you can define it as `List<List<String>>` or what ever type you are getting for `f.data['activities']`. If not do type case `list as List<DATA_TYPE>`

Comment: okay like this: List<List<String>> activityDays = [];

it gives error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<String>>' of 'function result'

Comment: you can put a brakepoint in that line and see what DATA_TYPE you are getting, based on that you define the data type. As i am not able to guess the exact type.

Comment: Where should I put the breakpoint?